# JavaScript library to type Hindi with international keyboards

Tags: javascript, linux, angularjs, hindi

I am developing a website using `HTML5` and `AngularJS`. I want to develop a site in Hindi language. One requirement is that the site should allow to enter text in the Devanagari alphabet even in devices that do not have the appropriate keyboard.

Time ago I hot-linked a Microsoft bookmarklet that's no longer available (`http://ilit.microsoft.com/Bookmarklet/Script/Hindi.js`) which would convert from English to Hindi: you type "kya" and then get the corresponding Hindi characters.

Can you suggest tools to do the same, using this or other system?

Comment: Why do you need a bookmarklet to type Hindi?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario is any other way to input text in hindi?

Comment: I don't know if you can speak Hindi but your profile says you're from India. Don't you just have keyboards in your country? I'm pretty sure the problem is clear in your mind but you must be aware that you haven't really explained it to us.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Im from India but I need to input hindi next in normal keyboard

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario This is client's need not mine, they want to use normal keyboard and want to convert it from English to Hindi, see updated question

Comment: "normal" means "non-Indian", doesn't it? Alright, that finally makes sense.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario means Having English alphabets

Comment: I've reworded your question to hopefully make it more clear; I apologise in advance if I've messed anything. While "help me find a library" kind of questions are technically off-topic, I think we can give this the benefit of the doubt. Also, are virtual on-screen keyboards acceptable or you're looking for a pure conversion tool?

Comment: BTW, a simple Google search shows that your resource has simply moved to http://www.bhashaindia.com/ilit/Hindi.aspx

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario for using that I have to install web or desktop version right? And its for windows. I am using linux

Comment: Oh, I thought you had been using that in the past and wondered where it had gone. Feel free to edit the question and correct whatever I misunderstood.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario  I used it in past but that time I just needed to include the path(http://ilit.microsoft.com/Bookmarklet/Script/Hindi.js) , So I can use this for windows and linux. But this new site is not like that.

Comment: You can try http://www.gamabhana.com/?q=about+gamabhana

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download code from    http://www.gamabhana.com/?q=node/3

Extract downloaded folder. Now your folder have the following content 
[image]

gamabhana_js have all js files that you need. Open the index.html in browser and enter something in textarea. Then you can see corresponding Hindi fonts instead of English. You can edit that index file and use according to your need.

Following is a sample code that I edited If I click on hindi then I will get Hindi fonts instead of English

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./gamabhana_js/GA1000.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./gamabhana_js/GA0010.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./gamabhana_js/GA0640.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./gamabhana_js/gamabhanaLib.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="./gamabhana_js/fileio.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" >
gw1=null;
var hindi=false;
function myCustomOnInit()
{   try{

if(hindi==true){
                  gw1= new gamabhanaPhoneticHandler("elm1_ifr",'__devanagari__','__roman__','#gamabhana#');
                  gw1.MrAutoCor=true;
                  GphRegisterForMasterUpdates(gw1);
}
     }
     catch(e){}
}

function LanguageList_onchange() {
gw1.SetPriLanguage(document.getElementById('LanguageList1').value);
}

function arrangekbhelp()
{
document.getElementById('kbhelpdiv').style.left=(window.document.body.clientWidth-400) + "px";
if((window.document.body.clientWidth-400)<0)
 document.getElementById('kbhelpdiv').style.left=0 + "px";
}
function hindi1(){
hindi=true;
myCustomOnInit();
}

function togglekbhelp()
{
arrangekbhelp();
if(document.getElementById('kbhelpdiv').style.display=='block')
   document.getElementById('kbhelpdiv').style.display='none';
else
   document.getElementById('kbhelpdiv').style.display='block';

return;
}
window.onresize=arrangekbhelp;

</script>



<!-- TinyMCE -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        // General options
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect,langselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl",
        theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css : "css/content.css",
            oninit : "myCustomOnInit", 
        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url : "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url : "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url : "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js",

        // Replace values for the template plugin
        template_replace_values : {
            username : "omkar",
            staffid : "9383"
        }
    });
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->

</head>
<body>

<form>

<textarea id="elm1" name="elm1" rows="15" cols="80" style="width: 80%">   </textarea>

</form>
<button onclick="hindi1()">Hindi</button>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: good one.. but is there any library that can allow me to type in a particular in a particular language that you select? I'm using angular JS. any help would be appreciated